# How does Heroku know that your password was reported as compromised?

Tags: security, authentication, heroku, passwords

I'm just getting started with a Heroku server and when creating a password it stated

"Passwords that have been reported as compromised on another site cannot be used as your new password".

How does Heroku get this report? Is there a trusted public api that offers this service?

Answer (score 0):

Best guess:

They are using [Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/), which also provides an API.

Troy Hunt is collecting data breaches on this site and making them accessible.